# How to connect android market in an application?

Tags: android, google-play

How to connect android market in my android application?

Comment: you mean you want to launch the android market to a certain page and exit your app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to launch the android market app and point to a certain application on the market.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.test.TestApp"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Replace the "com.test.TestApp" with the package name of the application you want to point to.